# How can I get value from TextFields and Select by click on button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I use react with redux and material ui, and I need get data from TextField for order. I have next code:

```
<Select value={product.color_set[0].title}>
{
  product.color_set.map(item => (
    <MenuItem key={item.key} value={item.title}>{item.title}</MenuItem>
  ))
}
</Select>
```

Also I have button with onClick arrow function:

```
<Button raised color='primary' onClick={() => {add2Cart()}}>
  <AddBasketIcon/>Add to cart
</Button>
```

Comment: I don't see any `textField` nor the implementation of your `onClick`  handler. Most importantly i don't see any effort or code examples of you trying to solve **YOUR** problem.

Comment: Check [Material Doc](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field)

Comment: It's because I don't know how can I teke selected ManuItem from Select. When I'll get data I just get value in action, after in reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get selected value after change like this:

```
    <SelectField
      onChange={(event, key, payload) => console.log(event, key, payload)}
    >
      ...items...
    </SelectField>
```

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field

You can save to React state the value

https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/components-props-and-state.html

and then use it anywhere else, e.g. in text field or in function call after click of the button